# password protect website with .htaccess and .htpasswd - error - "Could not open password file:"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, password-protection, plesk, .htpasswd

We have Plesk site builder through our webhosting with Charter. Using it to create a simple development website.

I am trying to password protect the site using .htaccess / .htpasswd.

I keep getting this error no matter what I do:

```
[Wed Apr 06 09:02:57 2016] [error] [client 66.169.84.65] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /.htpasswd
[Wed Apr 06 09:02:57 2016] [error] [client 66.169.84.65] access to / failed, reason: verification of user id 'heather' not configured
[Wed Apr 06 09:03:52 2016] [error] [client 66.169.84.65] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
[Wed Apr 06 09:03:52 2016] [error] [client 66.169.84.65] access to / failed, reason: verification of user id 'admin' not configured
[Wed Apr 06 09:03:56 2016] [error] [client 66.169.84.65] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
[Wed Apr 06 09:03:56 2016] [error] [client 66.169.84.65] access to / failed, reason: verification of user id 'heather' not configured
[Wed Apr 06 09:05:11 2016] [error] [client 66.169.84.65] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /etc/httpd/HTTP/.htpasswd
[Wed Apr 06 09:05:11 2016] [error] [client 66.169.84.65] access to / failed, reason: verification of user id 'admin' not configured
[Wed Apr 06 09:05:15 2016] [error] [client 66.169.84.65] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /etc/httpd/HTTP/.htpasswd
[Wed Apr 06 09:05:15 2016] [error] [client 66.169.84.65] access to / failed, reason: verification of user id 'heather' not configured
```

I'm not very familiar with Parallels Plesk - and getting a hold of their support is like pulling teeth.

- I've checked and double checked the path to the .htpasswd file; seems right.
- I've moved it and the .htaccess file to see if I just
  don't have it in the right place

I'm not sure what the problem is. I get the authentication box (I notice it doesn't have my "Please Login" message though...

[image]

here is the code for the .htaccess file:

```
#
#           AUTHENTICATION
#
### BASIC PASSWORD PROTECTION
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/HTTP/.htpasswd
AuthName "Please Login"
AuthType basic

<Limit GET POST>
Require valid-user
</Limit>
```

ANY Help is greatly appreciated or leads in the right direction. THANKS IN ADVANCE!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. For me, `.htpasswd` was stored under the `/home/username/.htpasswds` directory. I solved the error by recursively making sure the directory is executable:

```
chmod +x -R /home/username/.htpasswds
```

Comment: this solution is safe? does not have a side effects?

Comment: This would also make the file executable, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 3):

Just generate /etc/httpd/HTTP/.htpasswd file by command:

```
# htpasswd /etc/httpd/HTTP/.htpasswd UserNameYouWant
```

it asks you for password and generate password file with user UserNameYouWant

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the file .htpasswd is there in /etc/httpd/HTTP/ directory. otherwise create 1 with the below command

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd heather
```

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04) you go for step by step configuration:

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `CentOS`, then probably `SELinux` is blocking access to that file if the file is outside the webserver root directory. (that's what happened to me).

## Solution

Move the file to your web server root directory then restore the file `SELinux` context using these commands :

```sh
mv /path/to/.httpasswd /var/www/html/
restorecon -v /var/www/html/.htpasswd
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a permissions issue if you think the file is in the right place.

Check the file ownership and permissions with:

```
ls -la /path/to/file
```

Make sure the file/group that your apache process runs as is able to read the file.

You can check the owner of the process by running:

```
ps -ef | grep apache
```

You should see the owner of the process in the leftmost column.

If file ownership is the issue, then use chown to change ownership:

```
sudo chown username: /path/to/file
```

You need to do this as root/sudo as non-root users don't have the right to change the ownership normally.

The : after the username changes the group over to the same as the username

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem on a Rackspeed server. It was because the file `passwd` was missing in `/home/company/.htpasswds/project/`